# Is it possible to delete cache in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, query-cache

My case is that I run several queries in Mongo and measure the response time. I know that Mongo uses Memory Mapped files and cache some data in RAM.

If I create an index and run a query the execution time is 2,07 seconds. When I run the query again the execution time is 0,017 seconds.

This means that the file is mapped into memory by the OS on the first access and the OS will keep it in cache until it decides to page it out.

Because I want to make some benchmarks I want somehow to remove the mapped results from memory.

```
free -g:

               total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached

Mem:            29          29          0          0          0         29
-/+ buffers/cache:          0         29
Swap:            0          0          0
```

I try `db.collection.getPlanCache().clear()` but it doesn't work.

Then I try:

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

I reboot my machine

```
sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
sudo service mongod start
```

Free -g:

```
               total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached

Mem:            29          0          0          0          0         0
-/+ buffers/cache:          0         29
Swap:            0          0          0
```

In above it seems that cache is free now. But when I execute again the query the execution time is 0,017 seconds. It seems that mongo has manage to cache or preserve the data somewhere. The desired execution time would be 2,07 seconds as I clear the cache.

Also `mongostat` gives:

```
insert query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize   res faults qr|qw ar|aw netIn netOut conn set repl     time
*0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 124.0G 248.9G 27.7G      1   0|0   0|0   79b    11k   13 rs0  PRI 12:37:06
*0    *0     *0     *0       1     5|0       0 124.0G 248.9G 27.7G      0   0|0   0|0  687b    11k   13 rs0  PRI 12:37:07
*0    *0     *0     *0       2     1|0       0 124.0G 248.9G 27.7G      0   0|0   0|0  173b    11k   13 rs0  PRI 12:37:08
*0    *0     *0     *0       1     5|0       0 124.0G 248.9G 27.7G      0   0|0   0|0  687b    11k   13 rs0  PRI 12:37:09
*0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 124.0G 248.9G 27.7G      0   0|0   0|0   79b    11k   13 rs0  PRI 12:37:10
```

Can anyone tell me how I can actually delete the cached results in Mongo?

Comment: I see you have also asked this question on the [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208232/is-it-possible-to-delete-cache-in-mongo) StackExchange site. Since that question has an answer perhaps you should delete this question.